# How to get the complete webpage after scrolling

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I would like to get a webpage. It has a list of recipies, however to access them all you have to scroll down for them to load. I am using the requests_html libary to get the webpage. I read up around this and saw people saying that you can change the request to make it give "subpages" of the webpage, however it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also tried to add `scrolldown=2000, sleep=2` to the `resp.html.render()` function, however that doesn't seem to make a difference either. Here is a some example code:

```
from requests_html import *
from bs4 import *

def get(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    resp = session.get(url)
    resp.html.render()
    data = resp.html.html
    resp.close()
    session.close()
    html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    print(len(html.find_all("div", class_="search-results-matrix__item"))) #this prints how many recipies were found, which always gives me 20 which is how many are seen before scrolling

get("https://app.ckbk.com/search?q=recipes&sort=popularity&book_full_title%5B0%5D=Splendid%20Soups&p=1")
get("https://app.ckbk.com/search?q=recipes&sort=popularity&book_full_title%5B0%5D=Splendid%20Soups&p=5") #here I tried to change the last bit of the request to p=5 rather than 1, as that is what changed when I scrolled
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to make a call to the site's JSON API that would return all the information you need. I suggest you `print(j)` to see the structure of the returned data:

```
import requests
import json

search = "Splendid Soups"
# up to 500 returned
post_data = """{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"simple_query_string":{"query":"recipes","fields":["authors^15","book_authors^12","title^10","title.exact^10","name^10","subtitle^5","subtitle.exact^5","book_title^2","book_full_title^2","book_subtitle","country^2","ingredients","ingredients.exact","additional_keywords","diet_type^2","course","skill","headings","book_licensor"],"default_operator":"and"}},{"match_phrase_prefix":{"full_title":{"query":"recipes","boost":300}}}]}},{"term":{"_type":"Recipe"}}]}},"post_filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"label3":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"label.raw":{"terms":{"field":"label.raw","size":50}},"label.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"label.raw"}}}},"country6":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"country.raw":{"terms":{"field":"country.raw","size":50}},"country.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"country.raw"}}}},"course7":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"course.raw":{"terms":{"field":"course.raw","size":50}},"course.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"course.raw"}}}},"diet_type8":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"diet_type.raw":{"terms":{"field":"diet_type.raw","size":50}},"diet_type.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"diet_type.raw"}}}},"skill9":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"skill.raw":{"terms":{"field":"skill.raw","size":50}},"skill.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"skill.raw"}}}},"era10":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"era.raw":{"terms":{"field":"era.raw","size":50}},"era.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"era.raw"}}}},"authors11":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"authors.raw":{"terms":{"field":"authors.raw","size":50}},"authors.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"authors.raw"}}}},"book_full_title12":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}}]}},"aggs":{"book_full_title.raw":{"terms":{"field":"book_full_title.raw","size":50}},"book_full_title.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"book_full_title.raw"}}}},"book_title13":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"is_licensed":true}},{"term":{"is_indexable":true}},{"term":{"book_full_title.raw":"xxxxx"}}]}},"aggs":{"book_title.raw":{"terms":{"field":"book_title.raw","size":50}},"book_title.raw_count":{"cardinality":{"field":"book_title.raw"}}}},"no_filters_top_hits":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"_source":false}}},"size":500,"from":0,"sort":[{"rank":{"order":"desc"}},{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}],"suggest":{"text":"recipes","suggestions":{"phrase":{"field":"title","real_word_error_likelihood":0.95,"max_errors":1,"gram_size":4,"direct_generator":[{"field":"title","suggest_mode":"always","min_word_length":1}]}}}}"""
post_data = post_data.replace("xxxxx", search)
url = f"https://app.ckbk.com/es-search/_search"
r = requests.post(url, json=json.loads(post_data))
j = r.json()

hits = j['hits']['hits']
print(f"{len(hits)} recipes found\n")

for hit in hits:
    print(f"{hit['_source']['title']} - {', '.join(hit['_source']['book_authors'])}")
```

This would give you output starting:

```
273 recipes found

Senegalese Peanut Soup - James Peterson
Tomatillo and Sorrel Soup with Hominy - James Peterson
French Pork and Cabbage Soup - James Peterson
Swiss Chard, Parsley, and Garlic Soup - James Peterson
Foie Gras and Truffle Soup - James Peterson
```

This post format was found by looking at the request made in my browser's network tools.

The browser in effect makes this call and than takes the returned JSON to format it into HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer it worked perfectly. Could you just explain two things. Firstly how did you figure out the method of getting it with the JSON API, or is that just a standard method? Also what are you refering to when you say you looked at the request made with your browser's networking tools?

Comment: Only issue I had is it capped the results at 500, meaning if 1000 were available it would only give me 500, but it was a pretty simple fix as I just found one of the fields in the `post_data` called `size` and changed it to whatever size I needed.

Comment: I used Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+E opens the developer network tools which lets you inspect all web traffic including headers and data. Other browsers have similar tools. Simply open the website you need click on the button you need and watch what happens.

Comment: The `post_data` that the site needs is IMHO overly complicated but was found using the network tools. If you take a look inside the JSON in my script, you will see the parameters for how many results you want e.g. `500` and where to start from `0`. You should perhaps poll this say 100 at a time rather than simply requesting a huge amount.

Comment: Ok thanks. I found how you got it. Why do you suggest poll it 100 at a time rather than request a large amount?

Comment: It could in theory put strain on their website. If they detect webscraping as the problem they could block you or put additional hurdles in place to make it harder. One approach is to also put a short delay between requests.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Thank you for your help